# How to batch convert a specific DTS audio track language of multiple MKV files to Dolby Digital?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, matroska, audio-conversion

I now the tool PopCorn MKV AudioConverter to convert all DTS audio tracks of a MKV file to DD. It is able to convert multiple MKVs in a folder as well. But it is not able to convert only if:
- MKV does not contain DD
- select specific language
- convert only the the first / best DTS audio track eg DTS-HD Master Audio

Is there an other way to find all MKVs in a folder that miss a DD audio track and then convert the eg japanese DTS audio track and only one / the best of them?

The target is to stream movie files on a TV with speakers which both support only DD, but many of the movies contain only DTS audio tracks. In addition some of the movies already contain DD audio tracks which should be ignored. And some movies contain multiple DTS audio tracks because of different languages (en, fr, jp, etc.) and quality (Stereo, DTS, DTS-HD MA, etc.).

Comment: Seems like a roundabout way to achieve a goal, but I don't know what that goal is. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to convert in the first place?

Comment: @llogan I updated the question.